# Does NoSQL Fit the Bill for Reporting Software?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, cassandra, nosql

I am currently developing a software system that imports and normalizes historical data in various formats (XML, JSON, CSV). As of right now, we are using SQL server, and are looking to find the best replacement for this tool (Postgres or NoSQL). 90% of the time, the (archived/historical/static)data is accessed via a web client, and is used in a READ only format with users picking and choosing canned reports. Changes to the data only occur to update incorrect information .

The replacement DB must be able to store and report on 10s of millions of rows very quickly, and scale across multiple servers with ease (data replication, clustering, etc). There must also be data integrity, so if I update one KPI (lets say Cost per Hr), then all the reports that rely on the KPI will be updated accordingly.

Having no prior experience with NoSQL databases, I am wondering if it is even the right choice to use in a reporting software. We would *like* to allow for users to create their own custom reports, and that means being able to query any data as opposed to our canned reports, but I don't know if this would throw a wrench in the comparison between SQL vs NoSQL.

Comment: I'm the CEO of a reporting software company and we have yet to have a single customer use us with a NoSql product as far as we know. And we have tens of thousands of customers. So short answer, unlikely you will find NoSql useful for reporting.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few too many variables in the question, to comfortably answer it in entirety, but here's an attempt.

- Your choice in `SQL` vs `NoSQL` should be based on data structure. Scalability is generally a second-tier concern, and is only slightly easy on some NoSQL platforms, but as always, isn't always free.
- If you're looking for 10s of millions of rows 'very quickly' you are seriously testing the limits of what you can do with it. An RDBMS would allow you a plethora of options at the cost of speed, and a NoSQL although quite fast an inputting at that speed, would make you code most of the RDBMS smartness in your application. Chose your poison.
- Updating a metric and 'automagically' updating reports is clearly a business-logic smartness, that shouldn't be tied down to platform selection.
- PostgreSQL has in the near past, really picked up a lot of arsenal to deal with file formats (`JSON` et al) and is clearly worth a try (sans easy scalability).

Having said that, you should really investigate Postgres' otherwise forgotten asset, FDWs. You can clearly consider using a NoSQL setup to ingest large unstructured data, and thence utilize postgres' powerful semantics to use that and create a asynchronous yet structured backend for your application. If done well, that could mean the best of both worlds.

Comment: Data structure is basically what we make of it. All of our clients have data in various structured and unstructured formats, but we normalize all data to our format in order to correctly show the KPI's. Everything relies on primary/foreign key relationships for our canned reports, making JOINS essential to correctly pull all the data in, thus making us code relational logic in, which I am not sure Mongo supports (in an efficient way, anyway). To address point 3, being that Mongo doesn't have joins, wouldn't it be difficult to add in data to a report from multiple docs/collections?